# International drug labeling guidelines

Tags: medications, labeling, guidelines

Are there any international guidelines regarding the labeling of drugs and pharmaceuticals?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). For future reference, it is always better if you show some of your own research in your question. For more information on how the site works please take our [tour] or visit the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, legislation of each country prescribes how medicines should be labeled. There are international guidelines, but national regulations always come first.

An example of international guidelines on labeling are the ones by World Health Organisation (WHO) given in [Guidelines on packaging for pharmaceutical
products; WHO Technical Report Series, No. 902, 2002](http://apps.who.int/medicinedocs/documents/s19638en/s19638en.pdf) which state that the label should contain at least:

> (a) The name of the drug product;
>
> (b)  a  list  of  the  active  ingredients  (if  applicable,  with  the  International  Nonproprietary  Names),  showing  the  amount  of  each
>   present,  and  a  statement  of  the  net  contents,  e.g.  number  of
>   dosage units, weight or volume;
>
> (c)  the batch number assigned by the manufacturer;
>
> (d)  the expiry date in an uncoded form;
>
> (e)  any special storage conditions or handling precautions that 
>   may
>   be necessary;
>
> (f)   directions  for  use,  and  warnings  and  precautions  that  may  be
>   necessary; and
>
> (g)  the name and address of the manufacturer or the company or the
>   person responsible for placing the product on the market.

Other example of international guidelines are those by European Medicines Agency in [Guideline on the Packaging Information of Medicinal Products for Human Use Authorised by the Union](http://ec.europa.eu/health/files/eudralex/vol-2/c/bluebox_06_2013_en.pdf) which is binding for the member states.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still seems problematic to me. If a European pharmacy labels a drug product according to the EU guidelines and sells it in another country, it should be fine. But if that product than enters a third party country, there seems to be no guarantee that the labeling is sufficient for that country.

Comment: @jack Labeling is usually done for each country the medicine should be marketed in. After all, the patients should be able to understand the label - if you label a medicine in, say, German and try to market it in France that would not be good. Regulatory agencies in each country actually have requirements for labeling before they issue a marketing authorisation.

Comment: There are pharmacies who sell their medicine to cargo ships, so the medicine enters different countries on a regular basis. Some countries' authorities are very particular about drug labeling (Nigera seems to be a pain-in-the-ass on that for some reason). And because a pharmacy cannot know in which countries a client's cargo ship is going to travel, it is virtually impossible to meet every countries labeling standards.